# mobile redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get an htaccess file to redirect. So that when the URL is- http://mobile.domain.tld/index.php?page=home

Apache actually requests http://mobile.domain.tld/index.php?page=home&template=mobile

What I have at the moment is-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.domain\.tld\/index\.php?page=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=(.+)$ index\.php?page=$1&template=mobile [QSA,L]
```

The mobile. subdomain is pointed at public_html but at the moment the "`&template=mobile`" parameter doesn't seem to be getting appended.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone plz reply my question about htaccess mobile redirect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178278/wordpress-site-sub-domain-mobile-site-redirect-for-inner-pages-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ page\.php?template=mobile [QSA,L]
```

You missed `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: I tested it on my website. It seemed to work. I'll check it once again.